# Delete multiple document in documentdb via code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have webservice that host in Azure.
My database is stored in cosomos-db. 
I want to delete multiple documents via c# code, according to some logic (not all the documents in the collection).
Can I delete multiple document via query ? (delete document one by one it's not efficient)

Tody I delete via the following code :

```
await _client.DeleteDocumentAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete each document individually.

If you don't want to make multiple client calls to Cosmos DB, you can execute your multi-delete in a stored procedure. This also has the advantage of treating all document deletes transactionally: everything either succeeds or fails, atomically, within the stored procedure.

Comment: Hi,  thanks , can you please give an example code of how to create stored procedure with parameters, via c# code , for delete multi documents according to some logic. Thanks

Comment: There is plenty of documentation for creating stored procedures with parameters. I suggest starting there, then posting a new question with specifics to deleting within a stored procedure. A quick search for `"documentdb bulk delete"` will help you find examples.

Comment: See [here.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/tree/master/samples/stored-procedures) There are also other samples.